# How to remove specific forked also local clone from main repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-clone, git-fork

I have created one private repository in GitHub, also given access to few more people to code along with me. Now I need to remove one guy from this particular repository.

He forked this repository and cloned it to his local system also. I need to remove both fork and local clone of his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to remove both fork and local clone of his.

Considering you (most likely) do not have access to "his local system", I believe you would need to request for that user to delete both (his fork on GitHub, and his local clone).

The [OP Ponsakthi Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5914958/ponsakthi-anand) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534375/how-to-remove-specific-forked-also-local-clone-from-main-repository-in-github/69536570#comment122913796_69536570):

> I will *not* have access to his system for sure. I wonder any change GitHub will remove it from his using git

Should you have access, then any removal will be the result of an action from your part, not of anything initiated from GitHub.

But since you don't, no automatic deletion will be done.

Comment: I will have access to his system for sure. I wonder any change GitHub will remove it from his using git command.

Comment: @PonsakthiAnand OK. Then any removal will be the result of an action from your part, not from anything initiated from GitHub.

Comment: @PonsakthiAnand No problem. I have included your comment in the answer, for more visibility.

Comment: OMG. I missed 'not' in my comment. Actually, I don't have access to his system. sorry for that

Comment: @PonsakthiAnand OK. I have revised the answer accordingly.